# Assertion generates argument which becomes a fallacy?

Tags: argumentation

When one makes an assertion does it automatically become an argument ?. answer this first before proceeding?

if No, where is the Distinction?

For example, one says "it is wet on the ground, therefore, it rained" which is either TRUE OR FALSE. if the assertion false does it become a fallacy argument

Comment: Usually, an [*argument*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument) has one or more premises and a conclusion. Thus, a single statement is not an argument.

Comment: An argument is [*valid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)) when it is not possible taht all the premises are TRUE and the conclusion is FALSE.

Comment: A [logical fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies) is a reasoning that is not valid.

Comment: If we read "it is wet on the ground, therefore, it rained" as an argument with *premise* "it is wet on the ground" and conclusiom "it rained", it is **not** valid because the argument form "p, therefore q" is not *valid*.

Comment: Well elaborated Thanks.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, an argument has one or more premises and a conclusion. Thus, a single statement is not an argument

An argument is valid when it is not possible taht all the premises are TRUE and the conclusion is FALSE

A logical fallacy is a reasoning that is not valid.

If we read "it is wet on the ground, therefore, it rained" as an argument with premise "it is wet on the ground" and conclusiom "it rained", it is not valid because the argument form "p, therefore q" is not valid.

CREDIT https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/4752/mauro-allegranza